# syntax error in PostgreSQL near customer_id

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I am trying to get all the customer name based on their id for that I am using the PostgreSQL function and passing it an array of customer id's

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public.list_of_customer(integer[]);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.list_of_customer(
    IN customer_ids integer[])
    RETURNS TABLE(id integer, name character varying) AS
$BODY$

BEGIN

    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT c.id, c.name
        FROM public.customers AS c
        WHERE c.id IN customer_ids;

END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

and call this function as:

```
select * from public.list_of_customer('{2740,2739,2738}');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need = ANY():

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.list_of_customer(
    IN customer_ids integer[])
    RETURNS TABLE(id integer, name character varying) AS
$BODY$
        SELECT  c.id
            ,   c.name
        FROM 
            public.customers AS c
        WHERE 
            c.id = ANY($1); -- <- Use = ANY()
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE; -- <- No need for plpgsql
```